# C# MVC 2 HtmlHelper to generate Table Columns with Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I'm after an MVC2 custom htmlHelper that will allow me to dynamically create X amount of columns given the data.

Say for instance I have a Zoo class which contains a list of Animals (which also contains a sub class). Ex:

```
public class Zoo
{
  public List<Animals> myAnimals;
}

public class Animals 
{
  public string year;

  public WarmClimate warm;

  public class WarmClimate {
    public string hippo;
    public string zebra;
    public string elephant;
    etc...
  }
}
```

and I want to create a table similar to the following.  Essentially creating a  column for every list of Animals I have.  Could be 4 columns worth of data or could be 30.

```
   |             | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
   | hypo        | 6    | 1    | 7    |  0   |
   | zebra       | 1    | 1    | 2    |  1   |
   | elephant    | 1    | 1    | 3    |  0   |
```

I currently have something like this; which is quite basic. Simply a for loop that iterates over the list grabbing the defined property value. If there were 100 animals in my class, a page with 100 for loops like this is a nightmare.

```
<tr>
    <td>Zebras: </td>
    <% 
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.myAnimals.Count; i++)
        {
    %>
        <td><%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.myAnimals[i].warm.zebra) %></td>
    <%
        }
    %>
</tr>
```

I Would like to replace that with a custom htmlhelper that would allow me to do something like:

```
<tr>
  <td>Zebras: </td>
  <%= Html.MyCustHelper( property?? , list??, expression??) %>
</tr>
```

MyCustHelper would return the appropriate html with NAME attribute populated correctly for model binding, much like it does when I use `Html.EditorFor()` helper, ex:

```
<td><input name="myAnimals[2].warm.zebra" id="myAnimals_2__warm_zebra" type="text" value="1"></td> etc.... etc...
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, but I assume there would be a simple way to output repeatable columns worth of data.

Can anyone help out with an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Also feel free to let me know that I am going about this all wrong.  No action on this, so no sure if its because I haven't explained it in a way that is understandable or its too complicated

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need a custom helper when an EditorTemplate should do what you want.  You would still use EditorFor, but use a template with it.

Basically, you just specify the template name with your EditorFor:

```
<tr>
    <td>Zebras: </td>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyAnimals, "Zebras") %>
</tr>
```

I have long forgotten the WebForms syntax for this, but it would be something like this.  Create an EditorTemplates folder and in that create a file called Zebras.ascx and add the appropriate WebForms @directives for strongly typed model.

```
<td><%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.warm.zebra) %></td>
```

Editor Templates automatically iterate over the collection, so you don't need the index, and it automatically generates the correct naming convention.

Read the 5 part series here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Unfortunately, I stopped being able to think in WebForms code quite some time ago, so I can't give you a real example.

Comment: thanks Mystery Man,  I was beginning to think my question was invisible (or too ridiculous).

I thought about going the EditorTemplate route, but the reason I was after an html helper was that it could allow for a little more flexibility and a single point of editing.  For instance I am going to have some classes and data attributes assigned to the columns/inputs created to tie in with some client side jQuery.  With an htmlhelper I can use the forloop to dynamically add anything else that is needed.

Comment: @BetardFooser - You're way too vague.  I see no reason why you can't add attributes in an editor template either.  I also don't understand what you mean by "a single point of editing".  If you mean you want a single template for all your animal types, then that's relatively easily done as well, by using the "additional view model data" field of editor templates.  They are very powerful, and very flexible.

Comment: @MysteryMan Sorry I mean dynamically based on the for loop counter... for instance adding different classes or data attributes based on the count and/or value.

Comment: @BetardFooser - Then all you have to do is change the model type of the template to be of your collection type and you can do that too.